# Having trouble clicking on an element in an automated test

Tags: c#, watin

I am currently building a test harness for the company I work at.  I have experience both with `C#` and `WatiN` and have never encountered the issue I am now having.

Below, is a snippet of the markup for the page giving me the issue:

```
<div id="toggle1" class="NavLayout toggle">
     <span onClick="toggleMenu(1, false);">
          <span id="toggletext1">Quote Processing</span>
     </span>
</div>
```

As you can see, I have a div, 2 spans and an image.  I am using WatiN to try and click the image, that will then expand the menu, exposing yet another layer that I will need to click something else on.  The problem I am having is in getting the 'Click' to happen.  From what I can see in the snippet, it seems to me I need to be able to click the  event, but cannot 'find' it with the code.

Any help out there to be had?

Comment: I'm not seeing your markup.  I see you're new, so double-check that you are displaying the markup as code (indent four spaces or highlight and click the code button above the editor).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have also had issues with clicking on certain elements.

I've run into issues where I could only click on an element if it was highlighted by mousing over the element.

Since I cannot see your code snippet, I can't tell if there is any javascript that deals with mouseover associated with the image, but if there is, you can try the following:

`img.FireEvent("onmouseover");`

`img.FireEvent("onmousedown");`

`img.FireEvent("onMouseup");`

You might also might want to try `img.FireEvent("onclick")` as well.

These are all guesses, since I can't see your code.  It's also possible that rather than clicking on the image element itself, that you may want to try clicking on the parent object.

EDIT:
Ok, now that I can see your code, it appears that you should fire an onClick event against the span with the 'onclick' code in it.

I don't see an image listed in your code snippet, but this code should call the parent of the lowest level span.

```
Watin.Core.Span span = browserinstance
                       .Span(Find.By("innertext", "Quote Processing"));
span.Parent.FireEvent("onclick");
```

Answer (score 1):

The DOM content that you intended to post is not visible. You might want to edit your post and check if it is visible. 

In order to click on images

```
Watin.Core.Image img = browserinstance.Image(Find By Constraint);
if (img!=null and img.Exists) 
img.ClickNoWait(); 
OR
img.FireEvent("onclick");
```